# Java collection initialisation while declaration vs null check

Tags: java, performance, collections

Are there any major disadvantages of initializing a Java collection, e.g. ArrayList at the time of declaration such as :

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The main purpose is to avoid the clutter of null checks while retrieving the elements.

Thanks

Comment: Some more information about the situation would be useful

Comment: What are you comparing this declaration to? The performance of this declaration is better compared to ...?

Comment: Any asnwer about arraylists can be marked as an answer for this question. be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the only disadvantage is that you may end up with a whole bunch of collections doing nothing and have unnecessarily done work to create the collection.

My personal preference is to assign a valid collection always unless there's a definite reason to avoid the memory and initialization overhead, such as within loops and other possible performance considerations. And if I was always ensuring the objects were initialized to non-null I ***would not*** then do redundant null-checks before using the collections.

The caution I would add is to make sure if you do use the collection that you *use* it and don't, in later code, replace it with an entirely new collection (that would indicate a probable design flaw). To enforce this you can declare the collection as final.

Comment: If the collection reference is never reassigned, I would declare it `final` as well.  Then you know it's initialized and never null.

Comment: that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use case:

- **Method body** declaration - always ok.
- **Static field** declaration - should always be ok.
- **Field declaration**. There are two popular cases - when you always need it initialized or when it might be `null`. In the first case I make it `final` and prefer initializing in a constructor. If it might be `null`, I add a lazy getter and annotate it with `@Nullable` like this:

```
@Nullable
List<String> strList;

...

public final List getList(){
    if(strList == null){
        strList = new ArrayList();
    }
    return strList;
}
```

This technique helps me to eliminate ambiguity of field states.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost always initialize right away. Just because it's initialized doesnt mean you shouldnt do null checks anymore. Creating the object and an if check have almost no effect on performance. Only when you're creating a list that has to copy objects from other collections or arrays

Comment: This advice doesn't scale. Create "an" object has no material effect on performance; creating *a million* objects in a tight loop will, not only for the allocation and initialization but with the additional load on GC.